# how to use 'linenumbers ' in django

Tags: python, django

this is my django code:

```
{{ 'one<br/>two<br/>three'|linenumbers}}
```

and it show :

```
1. one
two
three
```

i want to know , how to show this using  'linenumbers' :

```
1. one
2. two
3. three
```

thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `<ol>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never used before, but [Django Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linenumbers) says you should be using a return character.

in your views:

```
text = """
    ONE
    TWO 
    THREE
"""
```

then in your template:

```
{{ text|linenumbers }}
```

shows 1. ONE 2. TWO 3.THREE

EDIT:

How ever every time I have had to do this, I usually do something like:

```
{% for n in lines %}
    <div>{{ forloop.counter }}. {{ line }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: And add the `<br />`s as well if you want to see line breaks in the HTML. The important thing is that the filter just looks for newline characters, not any sort of HTML tag.